# Rxjava2 unit test for polling data is failing

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2

I have this code and wish to unit tests this code.

```
    fun latest(): Single<Rates> {
        return service.latest()
    }

    fun pollingLatest(): Observable<Resource<Rates>> {
        return Observable.interval(DELAY_PULLING_LATEST_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap {
                latest().toObservable()
                    .map<Resource<Rates>> { rates ->
                        Resource.Success(rates)
                    }
            }
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
    }
```

The below is my unit test code for success.

```
    fun `when polling latest is successful, it should provide the rates`() {
        val rates = mockk<Rates>(relaxed = true)
        every { service.latest() } returns Single.just(rates)
        Repository(service, Schedulers.trampoline())
            .pollingLatest()
            .test()
            .awaitCount(1)
            .assertValue(Resource.Success(rates))
            .assertNotComplete()
    }
```

However I have the below error message.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: Success(data=Rates(#5)) (class: Success) but was: [] (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!)
Expected :Success(data=Rates(#5)) (class: Success) 
Actual   :[] (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0, timeout!)
 <Click to see difference>


    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.fail(BaseTestConsumer.java:189)
    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.assertValue(BaseTestConsumer.java:354)
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the Problem, but by default `interval` operates on the computation scheduler. You can try `Observable.interval(DELAY_PULLING_LATEST_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline())` just to see if it helps and if it does I can write an answer with a better approach.

Comment: @Fred thanks for your reply, however it does not work. the problem is latest().toObservable() is not emitting anything, but in real, it is working fine. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.